# How to define candle Upper/Lower and body color for line.new

Tags: pine-script

Afternoon all,

I cant seem to get my head around where I am going wrong.

What I am trying to do is determine the color of line new based on where price is within a candle:

If price is within candle body color equals blue

If price is lower wick color equals green

If price is upper wick color equals red

```
UW = max(open, close) > high
LW = low < min(open, close)
CandleBody = max(open, close) < min(open, close) and max(open, close) > min(open, close)

show_BTSL = input(true, title = "Show Candle Color", type = input.bool)
WickandCandleColor =  show_BTSL ?
     UW ? color.red : 
     LW ? color.green :
     CandleBody ? color.blue :
     color.blue :
     na
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep in mind that `close` on the realtime bar is the current price, so on that bar, your code will not behave the way you expect.
2. Your conditions need refinement. `max(open, close) > high` for example, will never be true. This neither: `max(open, close) < min(open, close)`, as the maximum between two values can never be less than the minimum between the same values.